# Unable to send JSESSIONID as part of the request

Tags: jmeter

I am working on developing a JMeter script for xlsx file export. When that step is executed manually I observed that cookie sent as part of Request Headers has 2 JSESSIONIDs. 1 of the JSESSIONIDs is generated in this step.
I developed script which has HTTP Cookie Manager under Test Plan. When this script is executed I observed that only 1 of the 2 JESSSIONIDs is sent. The other JSESSIONID which is being generated in that step is not sent. This transaction obviously fails. On checking the JMeter log I Observed that :

```
DEBUG o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Received Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.NodeY; Path=<PATH>; Secure; HttpOnly From: <URL of the application>

DEBUG o.a.j.p.h.c.CookieManager: Add cookie to store <URL of application>   TRUE    <PATH>  TRUE    0   JSESSIONID  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.NodeY

ERROR o.a.j.r.ResultSaver: Error creating sample file for <Transaction Name>

java.io.FileNotFoundException: <Location where file is to be exported to> (Access is denied)
```

Could it be that I am receiving the error because the 2nd JSESSIONID as mentioned above is not sent. I don't think this error is because of any access related issue because I do have the access to the folder in which the file is to be downloaded. Probable reason could be that the 2nd JESSSIONID is not sent as part of the request.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is not connected with [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) in general and with JSESSIONID in particular.

It's connected with [Save responses to a file listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file), either you've configured it incorrectly or your user doesn't have sufficient [permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions) to create a file in the specified folder.

First of all make sure to add a trailing slash (or backslash, depending on your operating system) and if it doesn't help check the target folder permissions.

[image]

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload & Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: Dmitri T - Thanks for your response. I tried disabling Save responses to a file listener even then my transaction is failing. I am getting 500 Internal Server Error.